# Batch stops after setting variables

Tags: file, batch-file, variables

I'm new to batch scripting and just tried to do some simple stuff and trigger some other applications. At first my batch set some variables and then it should save the results from a command to a file. Both parts alone work fine, but if I put them together it stops after setting the variables. Can someone help me?

Code:

```
set path=%cd%
set filename=\MAC.txt
set filepath=%path%%filename%
arp -a |find "192.168.1.1">>%filepath%
pause
```

Comment: `%path%` is a system variable that tells windows where to find it's commands. DON'T change it, unless you exactly know what you are doing and why. Use another varaiblename, for example `%mypath%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `path` is the variable used by `cmd` for finding executables, changing it to something where `arp` *isn't* will mean that you won't be able to locate and run `arp`.

Use a different variable name, such as:

```
set filepath=%cd%
set filename=\MAC.txt
set fullname=%filepath%%filename%
arp -a |find "192.168.1.1">>%fullname%
pause
```

Note that this still has another problem present in your original script, the fact that spaces in your current directory may cause issues (unless you quote them correctly).

Since you're using the current directory exclusively, you probably don't need to worry about the path:

```
set fullname=.\MAC.txt
arp -a |find "192.168.1.1">>%fullname%
pause
```